# How to change directory in batch file?

Tags: maven, batch-file

I have a batch file as follows

```
E:

cd E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\core

mvn clean install

cd E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\handset

mvn clean install
```

It'll run the `mvn install` command for core

but it won't execute the `mvn install` command for handset project.

Comment: does mvn exist in the handset folder?  Is it a batch file?

Answer (score 2):

This is another method of changing drive and folder.

The `call` commands are to solve the issue if mvn is a batch file.

```
cd /d "E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\core"
call mvn clean install

cd /d "cd E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\handset"
call mvn clean install
```

mvn must exist in both those folders for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
pushd "E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\core"
mvn clean install
popd

pushd "cd E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\handset"
mvn clean install
popd
```